# Ignore 'views' in mysql db backup using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I need to ignore all view in my database and take backup using mysqldump. Currently i am using below option.

```
--ignore-table=view1 --ignore-table=view2 --ignore-table=view3
```

Is there any way to take backup omitting all views without specifying all 'view' names.?

Answer (score 26):

If the MySQL user you're using doesn't have access to read Views, then just putting an `-f` flag on the `mysqldump` command will skip them. Unfortunately, it prints a warning which might be annoying, but it will otherwise complete the dump.

Comment: What a nice idea! It works for me well! This is the most convenient way for doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Usage

```
php mysqldump.php mydatabase myusername mypassword > myoutputfile.sql
```

This is a pretty old script of mine. Someone could easily adapt this to use PDO if you do not have access to the mysql functions.

```
<?php

if (is_array($argv) && count($argv)>3) {
    $database=$argv[1];
    $user=$argv[2];
    $password=$argv[3];
}
else {
    echo "Usage php mysqdump.php <database> <user> <password>\n";
    exit;
}

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $password);


if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$source = mysql_select_db('$database', $link);
$sql = "SHOW FULL TABLES IN `$database` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$views=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $views[]="--ignore-table={$database}.".$row[0];
}
    //no views or triggers please
system("mysqldump -u root --password=\"$password\" $database --skip-triggers ".implode(" ",$views));

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h host [some options here] `',`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'` `',
`TABLE_NAME`,'` > ',`TABLE_NAME`,'.sql') AS `sql` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
WHERE `TABLE_TYPE` != 'VIEW'
AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` NOT IN ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA','mysql');
```

Comment: I guess this works. Then you concat all files and now you have a single dump.