# Is it possible to dump and import views using mysqldump?

Tags: view, mysql

When I use mysqldump and the re-import the dump, the views become empty tables.

Is it possible to either

a) dump and then import views without turning them into empty tables?

or, if a is not possible,

b) exclude views from mysqldump with a wildcard, such as

```
mysqldump mydb  --ignore-table=*views > mydb.sql
```

to exclude all views, if all views have names ending with the string "views"? (this part has been previously asked but remains unanswered: [Ignore 'views' in mysql db backup using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8520330/199217))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--compact --add-drop-table` and then manually adjust the dump file.

Details:

`--compact`

Produce more compact output. This option enables the `--skip-add-drop-table, --skip-add-locks, --skip-comments, --skip-disable-keys, and --skip-set-charset` options.
Note:

Prior to MySQL 5.1.21, this option did not create valid SQL if the database dump contained views. The recreation of views requires the creation and removal of temporary tables and this option suppressed the removal of those temporary tables. As a workaround, use --compact with the --add-drop-table option and then manually adjust the dump file.

Comment: thanks. now I just need to convince the admins to update from 5.0.77

Comment: what do you mean by "manually adjust the dump file"? What would need to be done and how would it differ before or after 5.1.21?

Comment: Could you please explain what does it mean to manually adjust the dump file?